# Recursive with void method?

Tags: java, point, void

I have a problem with one of my program (my programming language is java) : 
I have an object Douglas-Peucker which is an array of Points and I have an algorithm, the Douglas-Peucker algorithm. I want to work directly on this array of Points and here the problem begin. This is Douglas-Peucker algorithm :

```
protected Point[] coinImage;
```

// My constructor

```
public Peucker(Point [] tab) {
    coinImage = new Point[tab.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < coinImage.length; i++) {
        coinImage[i] = new Point(tab[i].x, tab[i].y);
    }
}
public Point[] algoDouglasPeucker() {
    return douglasPeuckerAux(0,coinImage.length - 1);
}

public Point[] douglasPeuckerAux(int startIndex, int endIndex) {
    double dmax = 0;
    int index = 0;
    for(int i  = startIndex + 1; i < endIndex; i++) {
        double distance = this.distancePointSegment(this.coinImage[i], this.coinImage[startIndex], this.coinImage[endIndex]);
        if(distance > dmax) {
            index = i;
            dmax = distance;
        }
    } ***
    if(dmax >= this.epsilon) {
        Point[] recResult1 = douglasPeuckerAux(startIndex,index);
        Point[] recResult2 = douglasPeuckerAux(index,endIndex);
        Point [] result = this.unionTabPoint(recResult1, recResult2);
        return result;
    }
    else {
        return new Point[] { coinImage[0],coinImage[endIndex] };
        }
} 

*** my problem is here : both methods have a specific type of return : array of Point or I want to change this because I want to work directly on my attribut (coinImage).
```

How change this in void methods ? 
Help me please ! 
Sorry I forget one method : I also want to change the type of this method :

```
    public Point[] unionTabPoint(Point [] P1,Point [] P2) {
    Point[] res = new Point[P1.length + P2.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < P1.length;i++) {
        res[i] = new Point(P1[i].x,P1[i].y);
    }
    int k = 0;
    for(int j = P1.length; j < res.length; j++) {
        res[j] = new Point(P2[k].x,P2[k].y);
        k++;
    }
    return res;
}
```

She return the union of two array but without specific order.

Comment: I want to change the three methods : algoDouglasPeucker,DouglasPeuckerAux and unionTabPoint to void method. I want to work in object but it's not the case here. But How to change the three methods in void ? Because one of this is recursive...

Answer (score 4):

Well the basic layout for a void recursive method is like this:

```
int i = 0;
public void recursive(){
    if(i == 6){
        return;
    }
    i++;
    recursive();
}
```

You can keep looping the method, as it would return the the next line, of the method that called it. In this case, the return, would reach the '}' and terminate the method, as it is finished.

Hope I helped :D

Comment: Thank's everyone for your answers ! :)

Comment: Unless you want to overflow your stack, `i >= 6` might be a better idea, and also perhaps passing `i` as an argument, which may be more closely related to the OP's problem.

Comment: @AusCBloke why would if(i == 6) lead to stack over flow ?

Answer (score 1):

Java is doing call by reference. It is possible to use an local instance of your result and/or use it in your parameterlist, for example `method(x, y, Point[])` and force the method as a result, what is your method call. Like:

```
public void doSome(x,y) { x==0 ? return : doSome(x-1, y-1); }
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you looking for ...(if not pls clarify more)

```
public void douglasPeuckerAux(int startIndex, int endIndex) {
  ...
  Point[] newCoinImage = new Point[] { coinImage[0],coinImage[endIndex] };
  coinImage = newCoinImage;
}

public void unionTabPoint(Point [] P1,Point [] P2) {
  ...
  coinImage = res;
}
```